# Converting a long dataframe to wide dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is a systematic way to go from this:

```
x = {'col0': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
     'col2': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], 'col3': [12, 13, 14, 15]}
y = pd.DataFrame(data=x)
y
   col0 col1 col2 col3
0    1     a    x   12
1    1     b    x   13
2    2     a    x   14
3    2     b    x   15
```

To this:

```
y2
   col0  col3__a_x  col3__b_x
0     1         12       13
1     2         14       15
```

I was initially thinking something like `cast` from the reshape2 package from R.  However, I'm much less familiar with Pandas/Python than I am with R.

In the dataset I'm working with `col1` has 3 different values, `col2` is all the same value, ~200,000 rows, and ~80 other columns that would get the suffix added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need `pviot` and column faltten

```
s=pd.pivot_table(y,index='col0',columns=['col1','col2'],values='col3')
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s.add_prefix('col3_').reset_index()
Out[1383]: 
   col0  col3_a_x  col3_b_x
0     1        12        13
1     2        14        15
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I have got it to work.  However i do have a follow up question.  This solution applies to `col3` only, would there be a way to do this for say `col3 col4 col5 ... col10` all at once?  I can just do a loop of some kind if need be.

Comment: @ChaseGrimm you change try `s=y.set_index(['col0','col1','col2']).unstack(level=[1,2]);
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)`

Comment: Thanks, I went with `s = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Periods','factor'], columns=['decile','function'], values = list(df)[4:])` and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `set_index` and `unstack` if you don't have multiple values for resulting rows and columns otherwise you'll have to use a aggregation method such as pivot_table or groupby:

```
df_out = y.set_index(['col0','col1','col2']).unstack([1,2])
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   col0  col3_a_x  col3_b_x
0     1        12        13
1     2        14        15
```

Or with multiple values using groupby:

```
df_out = y.groupby(['col0','col1','col2']).mean().unstack([1,2])
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
df_out.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `pd.factorize` and Numpy slice assignment we can construct the data frame we need.

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.col0)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.col1.str.cat(df.col2, '_'))
b = np.zeros((r.size, c.size), np.int64)
b[i, j] = df.col3.values

d = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([r, b]),
    columns=['col0'] + ['col3__' + col for col in c]
)

d

   col0  col3__a_x  col3__b_x
0     1         12         13
1     2         14         15
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that @Wen 's solution is probably better, as it is pure `pandas`, but here is another solution if you want to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

d = y.groupby('col0').apply(lambda x: x['col3']).unstack().values
d = d[~np.isnan(d)].reshape(len(d),-1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(d).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'col0', 0: 'col3_a_x', 1:'col3_b_x'})

>>> new_df
   col0  col3_a_x  col3_b_x
0     0      12.0      13.0
1     1      14.0      15.0
```